# Detect any attempt to insert an email address or phone number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

How can I detect from input boxes any attempt to insert an email address or phone number.
This is the main scenario: we have some inputs where user should only write what they are for, like name or street or features.

How can I detect/verify after the user submits that in all that data he sends there are no: emails/phone numbers. Take in consideration that I also have to eliminate this kind of tries:
email at domain dot com, emails @ [spaces] dot [spaces] com and so on.

Are there any plugins, tools out there we can use? Do you have an idea about this? Let's put it to the test.

We are building a web application. (php/javascript mainly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for jQuery validation plugins there are tons of them.

E.g. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ or search Google for "jquery validation plugin"

Also validate your input server-side with php after submit, because Javascript can be disabled in the browser.

There are also many tutorials out there (e.g http://myphpform.com), or search SO.

Comment: That's the problem we don't try to validate a correct email input we want more than that. We want to catch any attempt to insert an email, even in this form: emailName at domain dot com. If there is any attempt to do that we want to catch it and launch an error.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for that. In the tutorial I postet you can see examples. If you search for regex tutorials you will also find loads of them e.g. http://php-regex.blogspot.com/ or http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html. You can also use regular expressions with Javascript.

Comment: So we should focus on regex to achieve our goal, as @NaveenKumar suggests as well.

Comment: Yes, with regex you will be able to achieve this. I suggest you to read through some tutorials, as it's good to understand them:)

Comment: sure, i was just into playing with regex right now :) thanks again, i hoped for a nicer approach to this, but regex here i come

Comment: Thank you! An example of matching yourATemailDOTcom based on the regex tutorial I postet would be: `$email = htmlspecialchars(strtolower($_POST["email"])); if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+at[\w\-]+dot[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{ die("email does not match"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery plugin for validation - then use regex (or some of the already built in functions) to validate the input ...

I use the [Position Absolute validator for jQuery](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
```

in Javascript

```
function validate()
{
         var regex =  /^[a-zA-Z_]+$/;
         var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
         if (regex.test(lname)) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;                    
         }

}
```

you can edit **regex** to suit your criteria